# which method (in spring API) called on /j_spring_security_check spring authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

my login page action is : /j_spring_security_check
now before it goes to my controller mapping, it call methods from spring API. I want to know what is the entry point for this URL.

I want to check for a condition and hence planning to override the called method so that I can override login in that method and then will call the super method anyway.

Any help (or please let me know if question is not clear)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be going about this the wrong way. Look into extending and customizing your own implementation of [AuthenicationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) . That link is the 3.0.8 version, but most versions of that interface are similar. Also, see this [tutorial](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-security-custom.html) (although there are many more out there).